# How to compare two oracle sql object type with common base super class

Tags: sql, oracle, inheritance, plsql, user-defined-types

Example:

1. Figure_t base class (super class)
2. sphere_t under figure_t
3. pyramid_t under figure_t
4. both has volume.
5. How to do objects comparison using map or order function?

What I am doing is using the map member function in the super class for comparing using the volume. I have tried with/without override of the map function in the subclass but still no luck. I can compare if I create the same object twice but not if I create different ones.

In example below I paste just the sphere since it is almost the same for both sphere and pyramid.

This is my super class:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE figure_t AS OBJECT (
    v_volume   NUMBER,
    v_area      NUMBER,
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN NUMBER, PRAGMA restrict_references ( compare, wnds, trust )
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY figure_t AS
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN v_volume;
    END;

END;
/

ALTER TYPE figure_t NOT FINAL
    CASCADE;
/
```

Then, this is my subtype:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sphere_t UNDER figure_t (
    v_radio NUMBER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sphere_t (
           radio NUMBER
       ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_volume RETURN NUMBER,
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_area RETURN NUMBER,
    OVERRIDING MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY sphere_t AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sphere_t (
        radio NUMBER
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        self.v_radio := radio;
        self.v_volume := ( 4 / 3 ) * 3.141592654 * power(radio, 3);

        self.v_area := 4 * 3.141592654 * power(radio, 2);
        return;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION get_volume RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN v_volume;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION get_area RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN v_area;
    END;

OVERRIDING
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN self.v_volume;
    END;

END;
/
```

For doing the comparison it looks like:

```
DECLARE
    sphere_v   sphere_t;
    pyramid_v   pyramid_t;
BEGIN
    pyramid_v := pyramid_t(120, 90, 30);
    sphere_v := sphere_t(10);
    IF ( sphere_v != pyramid_v ) THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('NOT EQUAL');
    END IF;
END;
```

There should be a way for this comparison since figures have a super class in common.

Answer (score 0):

> There should be a way for this comparison since figures have a super
>   class in common

Am not very sure as what you wanted to achieve here. Also what is definition of `pyramid_t` which you are using in your comparison.

> IF ( sphere_v != pyramid_v ) THEN

The above condition looks dicey to me as this will always be the case.

When you do `sphere_v := sphere_t(10);` means you try to get all the return of the `sphere_t` to `sphere_v`. 
So it would be good if you could compare the volume and area of the `Sphere` and `pyramid` separately. See below demo how you could take these value:

```
DECLARE
    sphere_v   sphere_t;
   -- pyramid_v   pyramid_t;

BEGIN               
    sphere_v := sphere_t(10);

    dbms_output.put_line('Input Radio     -->'||sphere_v.v_radio);
    dbms_output.put_line('Volume of Sphere-->'||sphere_v.v_volume);
    dbms_output.put_line('Area Of Sphere  -->'||sphere_v.v_area);

  --Similarly you can take the values of `volume` and `area` 
  --of pyramid and get it compared with that of Sphere.

  -- pyramid_v := pyramid_t(120, 90, 30); 
  --  dbms_output.put_line('Input Radio Pyramid -->'||pyramid_v.v_radio);
  --  dbms_output.put_line('Volume of Pyramid    -->'||pyramid_v.v_volume);
  --  dbms_output.put_line('Area Of Pyramid      -->'||pyramid_v.v_area);

  -- If sphere_v.v_volume = pyramid_v.v_volume then
  --   dbms_output.put_line('Equal');
  -- Else 
  --   dbms_output.put_line('Not Equal'); 

END;
```

Assumption: `pyramid_t` also have the same Object Body definition having volume and area calculation.

Comment: This feels like it could be boiled down to a comment, as it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @APC Isn't your answer is just repetition of what i showed above. I already showed how to compare a individual volume and you just showed the same using `compare` function. However i being definition of `pyramid_t` unknown , chose not to put it as answer rather make an assumption

Comment: I know that it does make lot of sense: 
```
IF ( sphere_v != pyramid_v ) THEN
```
But in theory you have the map member function and you can compare whatever you want given the conditions, and in this case if the context is: if two figures have the same volume then they are the same.  My question is not related with alternatives because there are many ways to achieve this but outside of map or order oracle functions.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> There should be a way for this comparison since figures have a super class in common.

There is a way, it's just not obvious.

When the types are exactly the same e.g. two instances of the same subtype we can invoke the map function implicitly. So we can compare two spheres like this:

```
 IF ( sphere_1 != sphere_2 ) THEN ...
```

However, to compare two different subtypes we need to invoke the parent map function, and to make this happen we must reference it explicitly:

```
 IF ( sphere_v.compare() != pyramid_v.compare() ) THEN ...
```

Yes, this is clunky. But Oracle is an RDBMS not an ORDBMS (whatever they claimed back in the version 8.0 days).

Comment: Thanks @APC, I already know this way. But with this methodology MAP or ORDER functions lose sense since it is the same than using a normal function. According to the requirements there is a way (I this this way you said is the way). I will post the answer if I find it.